# Construct multi column table from key,value pairs

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have the following JSON coming from a database table

```
[{"name":"field1","value":Jim,"tieRef":1},{"name":"field2","value":120.11,"tieRef":1}, 
{"name":"field3","value":AAA,"tieRef":1},{"name":"field1","value":Stacy,"tieRef":2},
{"name":"field2","value":34.10,"tieRef":2},{"name":"field3","value":BBB,"tieRef":2}]
```

And I need to construct an HTML table which looks like the below. The values related to the same row should be identified by the tieRef attribute.

```
field1 | field2 | field3
-------------------------
JIm    | 120.11 |  AAA
-------------------------
Stacy  | 34.10  |  BBB
```

Column names should be extracted from the "name" attribute. For extracting and summarizing the values under a single column I used the d3.js as listed below

```
var transformed = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
 .object(data);
```

By using this I was able to transform the original JSON in to the following

```
{"field1":[
    {"name":"field1","value":"Jim","tieRef":1}, 
    {"name":"field1","value":"Stacy","tieRef":2}],
"field2":[
    {"name":"field2","value":120.11,"tieRef":1}, 
    {"name":"field2","value":34.1,"tieRef":2}],
"field3":[
    {"name":"field3","value":"AAA","tieRef":1},
    {"name":"field3","value":"BBB","tieRef":2}]}
```

But I'm not sure this the correct transformation needed to make it easier for constructing the HTML table. Please suggest a better transformation of the JSON so I can loop through and construct the table

Does anyone know how to achieve this in an elegant way?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?  StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Well, I tried to use d3 to create a nested structure `var expensesByName = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .object(data);` But not sure whether this is the correct transformation I need to do to create the table. Also note that I did not ask for any code. I was asking for ways and hints, what functions and libraries I can make use of

Comment: Edit your question and put your code attempt in there.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How to know which elements belong to the same row? and what is the order of the columns you want. You need to construct a different dataset.

Comment: You have not supplied an HTML output, only a text one.  You have not explained how to know if two entries belong to the same row; how do we know `'AAA'` belongs to Jim and not Stacy?  You have not suggested whether the headers are supplied separately or extracted from these entries.  Most of all, you have not offered any sample of what code you've attempted.  I will remove my downvote and close vote if you fix these.

Comment: Oddly, I found the question interesting enough for me to make guesses at these questions and write a partial answer.  But I don't really want to share it if you don't put in the effort yourself.  (And I won't see this again until after a night's sleep.)

Comment: I voted to reopen given your updates.  I agree that this is not the output you want.I would expect that you should transform it to something like `[{field1: 'Jim', field2: 120.11, field3: 'AAA'}, {field1: 'Stacy', field2: 34.1, field3: 'BBB'}]` since building tables usually requires starting with rows.  Your question still needs work though.  See my suggestions several comments back.

Comment: ...or just start a new question with more information as reopens are fairly rare...

Comment: what if you key on `tieRef` and sort/reorder by columns in the `rollup` part.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try to key on the tieRef. But i believe it will still not help to get rid of the key, value pairs

Comment: you need the elements that belong to the same row, this is what key on `tieRef`does. What is the problem with the key value pairs?

Comment: Key on `tieRef` first and then on `name` did the trick. Thanks for all the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key on `tieRef` and then on `name` worked really well for transforming the JSON. first do the below using d3

```
var data = [{"name":"field1","value":"Jim","tieRef":1},
{"name":"field2","value":120.11,"tieRef":1},
{"name":"field3","value":"AAA","tieRef":1},
{"name":"field1","value":"Stacy","tieRef":2},
{"name":"field2","value":34.10,"tieRef":2},
{"name":"field3","value":"BBB","tieRef":2}];

var transform = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) { return d.tieRef; })
 .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
.object(data);
```

This will transform the JSON in to the below.

```
{"1":
  {"field1":
            [{"name":"field1","value":"Jim","tieRef":1}],
   "field2": 
            [{"name":"field2","value":120.11,"tieRef":1}],
   "field3": 
            [{"name":"field3","value":"AAA","tieRef":1}]
  },
 "2":
   {"field1": 
            [{"name":"field1","value":"Stacy","tieRef":2}],
    "field2": 
            [{"name":"field2","value":34.1,"tieRef":2}],
    "field3": 
            [{"name":"field3","value":"BBB","tieRef":2}]
    }
   }
```

This is then iterated by the row number `1,2,..` and constructed the table or further transform the JSON